# JPA pessimistic lock logic for client-server application

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, locking

I am learning JPA pessimistic lock. I found the following explanation

> PESSIMISTIC_READ - The Entity is locked on the database, prevents any
> other transaction from acquiring a PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock.
>
> PESSIMISTIC_WRITE - The Entity is locked on the database, prevents any
> other transaction from acquiring a PESSIMISTIC_READ or
> PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock.

If I understand it right, then if we have three users (A, B, C) and user A gets READ lock, then user B can get READ lock too, but user C can't get WRITE lock until users A and B releases their locks. And if user A gets a WRITE lock then user B and user C can't get nothing until user A releases the lock.

However, for my client-server application I want the following logic. If users want only to read an entity their open the entity in READ-ONLY mode (unlimited number of users can do it at the same time). If some user wants to edit the entity he opens it in WRITE mode - no one can open the same entity in WRITE mode (until the user releases the WRITE lock) but all other can still open the entity in READ-ONLY mode.

And I have two questions:

1. Is my understanding of JPA pessimistic lock right?
2. Is it possible to make JPA do the logic I need (using JPA lock mechanisms)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is my understanding of JPA pessimistic lock right?

Yes, that's exactly how read/write locking works

> ...but all other can still open the entity in READ-ONLY mode

I'm not exactly sure what you mean. We are still talking about multiple transactions executing simultaneously, right (I have a strange feeling that's not what you mean)? If that's the case, then in your logic, holding a 'READ_ONLY' lock accomplishes nothing.

Locking means 'I'm freezing this resource so that certain other transactions cannot proceed until I'm done'. But, in the logic you described, when you're holding the 'READ_ONLY' lock, both a transaction holding the 'READ_ONLY' lock and the transaction holding the 'WRITE' lock are allowed to proceed.

Comment: Please, note, that I am talking about read only `MODE`. It is like MS Office - when the first user opens a file all other can open the file, but only in READ-ONLY mode - they can read, but can not edit.

Comment: And yes, if some user opens in READ-ONLY mode then there is no any locks in the logic I want.

Comment: If I am reading your MS Office analogy correctly, you want to implement the functionality of locking a given entity that will last for an extended period of time. You're not just after implementing transaction isolation logic. In that case, JPA locking mechanisms will not help. You'll probably need to add a `boolean locked` or `String lockedByUser` property and implement the proper logic yourself